# For Each loop with promises not working in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, loops, angular-promise

The "types" parameter being passed in is in the format `["hourAverage","hourMedian","dayAverage","dayMedian","weekAverage","weekMedian","monthAverage","monthMedian"]`

Source:

```
$scope.buildCharts = function(types){
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    var promises = [];

    types.forEach(function(type){
                $scope.prepareData(type);
                deferred.resolve([
                {
                    title: type,
                    curveType: 'function',
                    legend: { position: 'bottom' }
                },type]);
                promises.push(deferred.promise);
    });
    return $q.all(promises);
};
```

Output:

```
[
  [
    {
      "title": "hourAverage",
      "curveType": "function",
      "legend": {
        "position": "bottom"
      }
    },
    "hourAverage"
  ],
  [
    {
      "title": "hourAverage",
      "curveType": "function",
      "legend": {
        "position": "bottom"
      }
    },
    "hourAverage"
  ],
  [
    {
      "title": "hourAverage",
      "curveType": "function",
      "legend": {
        "position": "bottom"
      }
    },
    "hourAverage"
  ],
  [
    {
      "title": "hourAverage",
      "curveType": "function",
      "legend": {
        "position": "bottom"
      }
    },
    "hourAverage"
  ],
  [
    {
      "title": "hourAverage",
      "curveType": "function",
      "legend": {
        "position": "bottom"
      }
    },
    "hourAverage"
  ],
  [
    {
      "title": "hourAverage",
      "curveType": "function",
      "legend": {
        "position": "bottom"
      }
    },
    "hourAverage"
  ],
  [
    {
      "title": "hourAverage",
      "curveType": "function",
      "legend": {
        "position": "bottom"
      }
    },
    "hourAverage"
  ],
  [
    {
      "title": "hourAverage",
      "curveType": "function",
      "legend": {
        "position": "bottom"
      }
    },
    "hourAverage"
  ]
]
```

Answer (score 2):

This illustrates that a promise can only resolve with one value. Any further call of `resolve` on the same deferred object will have no effect. That is why you get the first object as value over and over again. This is required behaviour by the [Promises/A+ specifications, point 2.1.2](https://promisesaplus.com/#point-14) (emphasis mine):

> 2.1.2 When fulfilled, a promise:
>
> 2.1.2.1 must not transition to any other state.
>
> 2.1.2.2 must have a value, **which must not change**.

Of course, if it *would* have been allowed to change the value of a promise, then you still would not have had the desired result, as then the result would have had a repetition of the *last* object value .

To solve this, create a new deferred object *within* the loop, so that you always resolve a new promise:

Move this:

```
var deferred = $q.defer();
```

Into the `forEach` callback:

```
types.forEach(function(type){
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    // etc...
```